# Make build independent of source root path

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to make my build independent of local workspace path and source code structure. 
This is my current workspace code organisation:

```
teamproject1  
   project1.1  
   project1.2  

teamproject2
   main
      project2.1

targetsfileproject
   import1.targets
   import2.targets
```

At this moment I work only with teamproject1. Targets files are referenced using

```
..\..\targetsfileproject\import1.targets
```

That, obviously, won't work with teamproject2. Is there a way to reference/set source root path  in msbuild files? Or some other way to make build independent of that path?

I found [this article](http://www.sneal.net/blog/2008/01/07/FindingTheRootSourceControlFolderUsingMSBuild.aspx) that should work for me, but I thought that simpler/cleaner solution should exist.

Comment: If you look inside your project files you'll see something like <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> so id use that model, and define a variable/env variable thats the root of all your projeccts and use that?

Comment: Every user can have different root (workspace path), so I can't define unified root variable. Anyway, I tried solution form article I posted and it works for me. It's ugly but functional.